# Codeigniter 3 blog application: how can I avoid using a redundant $config pagination array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8.

I have a **Posts** controller at

> application/controllers/Posts.php

I have a **Categories** controller at

> application/controllers/Categories.php

In the **Posts** controller I have:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url("/posts"),
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'query_string_segment' => 'page',
        'display_pages' => TRUE,
        'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
        'per_page' => 12,
        'total_rows' => $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows(),
        'uri_segment' => 3,
        'first_link' => '&laquo;',
        'first_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_link' => '&raquo;',
        'last_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'full_tag_open' =>  '<ul class="pagination">',
        'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
        'next_link' =>  '&rsaquo;',
        'next_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'prev_link' => '&lsaquo;',
        'prev_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open' =>   '<li>',
        'num_tag_close' =>  '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open' =>   '<li class="active"><span>',
        'cur_tag_close' =>  '</span></li>'
    ];
     // More code
}
```

The `$config` array in the Categories controller is *almost the same*:

```
public function posts($id) {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url' => base_url('/categories/posts/' . $id),
        'page_query_string' => TRUE,
        'query_string_segment' => 'page',
        'display_pages' => TRUE,
        'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
        'per_page' => 12,
        'total_rows' => $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows_by_category($id),
        'uri_segment' => 3,
        'first_link' => '&laquo;',
        'first_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_link' => '&raquo;',
        'last_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'full_tag_open' =>  '<ul class="pagination">',
        'full_tag_close' => '</ul>',
        'next_link' =>  '&rsaquo;',
        'next_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'prev_link' => '&lsaquo;',
        'prev_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open' =>   '<li>',
        'num_tag_close' =>  '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open' =>   '<li class="active"><span>',
        'cur_tag_close' =>  '</span></li>'
    ];
}
```

How could I make a "base" `$config` array which, for every controller it is used in, I would only have to write what is *specific*?

Comment: If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called pagination.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file in application/config/pagination.php and it will be used automatically. You will NOT need to use $this->pagination->initialize() if you save your preferences in a config file.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#setting-preferences-in-a-config-file

Comment: How would I use that in the *controllers*?

Comment: pls read the given above link < it will be used automatically >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to create a `pagination.php` configuration file an put all what you need in it.
The next time you load pagination library it will use this file and you may override what's stored in it using

```
$config['whatever'] = 'anything';

// Option: 1
$this->load->library('pagination', $config);

// Option: 2
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Almot all CodeIgniter libraries can have their own configuration files, no need to create a library or a helper or even a controller's method to handle what a configuration file can do.
You want to have constant pagination configuration for all your application, with the possibility to dynamically change it? Use the configuration file `pagination.php` and stop wasting your time and execution time writing a whole library or helper to handle that.

Comment: Where do I save this `pagination.php` file? And how do I call it?

Comment: `pagination.php` config file goes inside your `application/config` directory. You don't need to load it because when you load the library, this file is automatically used.

Comment: What exactly shall I write in the `pagination.php` file? That `$config` array I am already using in my controllers?

Comment: Yes. I gave you an example. Here is a link: https://github.com/bkader/skeleton/blob/2.0/develop/application/config/pagination.php

Answer (score 1):

You may create a library with a method and then use it in your entire application. Like I have a library `Nuts_lib.php` file with `generate_pagination()` method in `libraries` folder

```
public function generate_pagination($url, $total_rows, $per_page = 10, $num_link = 5) {
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url_tr($url);
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_link;
    $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination no-margin">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void();">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next >';
    $config['prev_link'] = '< Prev';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $this->CI->pagination->initialize($config);
    return $this->CI->pagination->create_links();
}
```

No I use it in controllers as follows

```
$total_rows = $this->db->get('routes')->num_rows();
$per_page = 15;
$num_links = 5;
$url = 'routes/all';
$links = $this->nl->generate_pagination($url, $total_rows, $per_page, $num_links);

    if ($this->input->get('page')) {
        $sgm = (int) trim($this->input->get('page'));
        $segment = $per_page * ($sgm - 1);
    } else {
        $segment = 0;
    }

    $data = array(
        'title' => lang('all_routes'),
        'routes' => $this->rm->get_all($per_page, $segment, $d, $t, $ttype, $i),
        'links' => $links,
        'segment' => $segment
    );
```

and then in view just

```
<?php echo $links; ?>
```

also increase `$segment` in loop like `$segment++`

Answer (score 1):

As per my idea,
You need to create one common function model and autoload that model in the `autoload.php`

For Reference please check the following code.

Create Model `Common_function_model` inside the `application/models`

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Common_functions_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_pagination_config($settings = array()) {

    $config = [
        'base_url' => isset($settings['base_url']) ? $settings['base_url'] : base_url(),
        'page_query_string' => isset($settings['page_query_string']) ? $settings['page_query_string'] : TRUE,
        'query_string_segment' => isset($settings['query_string_segment']) ? $settings['query_string_segment'] : 'page',
        'display_pages' => isset($settings['display_pages']) ? $settings['display_pages'] : TRUE,
        'use_page_numbers' => isset($settings['use_page_numbers']) ? $settings['use_page_numbers'] : TRUE,
        'per_page' => isset($settings['per_page']) ? $settings['per_page'] : 12,
        'total_rows' => isset($settings['total_rows']) ? $settings['total_rows'] : "",
        'uri_segment' => isset($settings['uri_segment']) ? $settings['uri_segment'] : 3,
        'first_link' => isset($settings['first_link']) ? $settings['first_link'] : '&laquo;',
        'first_tag_open' => isset($settings['first_tag_open']) ? $settings['first_tag_open'] : '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => isset($settings['first_tag_close']) ? $settings['first_tag_close'] : '</li>',
        'last_link' => isset($settings['last_link']) ? $settings['last_link'] : '&raquo;',
        'last_tag_open' => isset($settings['last_tag_open']) ? $settings['last_tag_open'] : '<li>',
        'last_tag_close' => isset($settings['last_tag_close']) ? $settings['last_tag_close'] : '</li>',
        'full_tag_open' => isset($settings['full_tag_open']) ? $settings['full_tag_open'] : '<ul class="pagination">',
        'full_tag_close' => isset($settings['full_tag_close']) ? $settings['full_tag_close'] : '</ul>',
        'next_link' => isset($settings['next_link']) ? $settings['next_link'] : '&rsaquo;',
        'next_tag_open' => isset($settings['next_tag_open']) ? $settings['next_tag_open'] : '<li>',
        'next_tag_close' => isset($settings['next_tag_close']) ? $settings['next_tag_close'] : '</li>',
        'prev_link' => isset($settings['prev_link']) ? $settings['prev_link'] : '&lsaquo;',
        'prev_tag_open' => isset($settings['prev_tag_open']) ? $settings['prev_tag_open'] : '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close' => isset($settings['prev_tag_close']) ? $settings['prev_tag_close'] : '</li>',
        'num_tag_open' => isset($settings['num_tag_open']) ? $settings['num_tag_open'] : '<li>',
        'num_tag_close' => isset($settings['num_tag_close']) ? $settings['num_tag_close'] : '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open' => isset($settings['cur_tag_open']) ? $settings['cur_tag_open'] : '<li class="active"><span>',
        'cur_tag_close' => isset($settings['cur_tag_close']) ? $settings['cur_tag_close'] : '</span></li>'
    ];
    return $config;
}

}
```

For Your `Post` Controller. Change your code to the following.

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $settings = array(
        "base_url" => base_url("/posts"),
        "total_rows" => $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows(),
    );

    $config = $this->common_functions_model->get_pagination_config($settings);
    // More code
}
```

For Your `Categories` Controller. Change your code to the following.

```
public function posts($id) {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $settings = array(
        "base_url" => base_url('/categories/posts/' . $id),
        "total_rows" => $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows_by_category($id),
    );

    $config = $this->common_functions_model->get_pagination_config($settings);
}
```

You can use `get_pagination_config` function at any Controller with those arguments you want to modify.

Please note that you need to autoload the `common_functions_model` in the `autoload.php` file.

Comment: Why `Common_functions_model` and not something more... illustrative, like  `Pagination_model`? And is there no need for a generic pagination controller too? Thanks!

Comment: @Razvan Zamfir You can give name of the controller as per your choice. No need to give name as common_functions_model.